# what if I need to modify bower contents?

Tags: bower

Please bear with me, I'm having a little trouble wrapping my head around this one...

On face value I know this questions seems foolish.  The answer us you DON'T modify your bower contents because anything you do is going to be overwritten each time the bower updates and you would have to reimplement the changes over and over.

But if the situation effectively requires that I modify the CSS stylesheet that styles one of my bower components how do I handle this?

The only solution that I can come up with would be to have my custom stylesheet style the same components, make sure it is called after the original bower stylesheet, and let my alterations cascade over the initial styling.

This will work fine for certain attributes (color, etc) but what about more "incremental" attributes? For example lets say the bower gives an item a left margin of 5px, but I set it to 2px.

Would my style cascading on top get negate the initial one or would they combine to give me a margin of 7px?

If they are added together does that mean I should reset these bower item attributes in the CSS reset at the top of my custom style sheet?

Sorry if this question is dumb or way off base, I just don't understand how I should handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS properties are not cumulative. They don't add together. If a property is set in multiple places, the property with [the most specific selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) wins and the rest are ignored. You can override properties set before by re-specifying them with a higher or equal specificity.

The correct way in this case is probably to override the few styles you need in your own stylesheet that is included after the component's stylesheet, as you said.